# Core Data value accessing error in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, swift

I was working with Core Data. After performing the fetch and reloading the UITableView app is crashing.

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell?
    {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        tasks = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Tasks
        cell.textLabel.text = tasks?.desc

        return cell
    }
```

I know that the error is in this part ->

```
    tasks = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Tasks
```

After reading some StackOverflow questions i added this code in to my existing cellForRowAtIndexPath UITableView delegate method.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell?
    {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

       var array : NSArray = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects as NSArray
        cell.textLabel.text = array.valueForKeyPath("desc") as NSString

        return cell
    }
```

Again the app is crashing in this point.

```
   var array : NSArray = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects as NSArray
```

i printed this by this code

```
println(self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects)

[<NSManagedObject: 0x16debcc0> (entity: Tasks; id: 0x16dd02f0 <x-coredata://A5AEB550-EB6D-4A47-9F6F-2F3AA49CA6BF/Tasks/p2> ; data: {
    desc = gghjg;
}), <NSManagedObject: 0x16ebb1d0> (entity: Tasks; id: 0x16e8cda0 <x-coredata://A5AEB550-EB6D-4A47-9F6F-2F3AA49CA6BF/Tasks/p1> ; data: {
    desc = gxshli;
})]
```

I don't know whats the problem with this. I followed the steps in this article [Core Data Example](http://rshankar.com/coredata-tutoiral-in-swift-using-nsfetchedresultcontroller/).

If Someone know whats the problem with this, please let me know. Thank You.

Here is the image for the crashing report.
[image]

Here is the full code of my ViewController source file class.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MaterTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIAlertViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    var fetchedResultsController : NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()
    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    var tasks : Tasks? = nil


    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add, target: self, action: Selector("insertNewObject"))

        // Update the ViewDidLoad method of TableViewController to populate fetchedResultController variable and set the delegate to self and call the function to retrieve the results.

        fetchedResultsController = getFetchedResultController()
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        fetchedResultsController.performFetch(nil)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: - Core Data Methods

    func insertNewObject()
    {
        if tasks != nil
        {
            self.editTasks()
        }
        else
        {
            var alertView : UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
            alertView.title = "Add Note"
            alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.PlainTextInput
            alertView.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel")
            alertView.addButtonWithTitle("Save")
            alertView.delegate = self
            alertView.show()

        }

    }

     func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int)
     {
        switch buttonIndex
            {
        case 0 : alertView .dismissWithClickedButtonIndex(buttonIndex, animated: true)
        case 1 :
            tempData = alertView.textFieldAtIndex(0).text
            self.saveThisValue(tempData)
        default : println("Nothin")
        }
    }

    var tempData : NSString = NSString()

    func editTasks()
    {
        tasks?.desc = tempData
        managedObjectContext?.save(nil)
    }

    func saveThisValue(input : NSString)
    {

        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Tasks", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
        let task = Tasks(entity: entityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
        task.desc = input
        managedObjectContext?.save(nil)

    }

    func getFetchedResultController() -> NSFetchedResultsController
    {
        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: taskFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        return fetchedResultsController
    }

    func taskFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest
    {
        let fetchRequest  = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Tasks")
        let sortDecriptor  = NSSortDescriptor(key: "desc", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDecriptor]
        return fetchRequest
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {

        return fetchedResultsController.sections.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        return fetchedResultsController.sections[section].numberOfObjects
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell?
    {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        tasks = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Tasks
        cell.textLabel.text = tasks?.desc

        return cell
    }


     func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController!)
     {
        fetchedResultsController.performFetch(nil)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an array of results, but `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is for just one result - so you need to use `indexPath.row` to get the particular element from the array

Comment: @Paulw11 I tried it. But again showing the same error. Can you please post some code here.?

Comment: What is the crash message you are receiving?

Comment: @Paulw11 i modified the question, please give me your feedback.

Comment: @Alvin Varghese: your image doesn't help us very much. When your app crash, click on the second, third and fourth row of Thread 1. What we need to know are the crash messages related to those rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell?
{
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let task = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath.row) as Tasks
    cell.textLabel.text = task.desc


    return cell
}
```

Comment: I did. It showing error in this line  ->    let task = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath.row) as Tasks // NSNumber is not a subtype of NSIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
let ob = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as NSManagedObject
var title : String = ob.valueForKey("keyname")!.description
```

in a recent app, the title was a list of string from the NSManaged Object

Jacko